# App Engine Backend Instance Timeout (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Currently I am using a dynamic backend instance for my site, but I still got timeout issue. The background of my site is:

1. GAE used as the frontend which handles user requests.
2. Requests will be sent to a EC2 rest server (using `bottle`) to process.

Below is the error information from GAE log. It seems like GAE stopped my backend thread after 60 seconds. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
ERROR    2014-02-20 14:42:18,365 module.py:660] Request to '/_ah/background' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 637, in _handle_request
    environ, wrapped_start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 1524, in _handle_script_request
    request_type)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 1476, in _handle_instance_request
    request_id, request_type)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\instance.py", line 382, in handle
    request_type))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\http_runtime.py", line 244, in handle
    response = connection.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

#### app.yaml

```
- url: /backend.html
  script: przm_batchmodel.py
```

#### backends.yaml

```
backends:
- name: mybackend
  class: B1
  instances: 1
  options: dynamic
```

#### Output.py

```
def loop_html(thefile):
    ####do some thing###
    response = urlfetch.fetch(url=my_REST_server_URL, payload=data, method=urlfetch.POST, headers=http_headers, deadline=6000)   
    return response

class przmBatchOutputPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        form = cgi.FieldStorage()
        thefile = form['file-0']
        html = background_thread.BackgroundThread(target=loop_html, args=[thefile, generate_batch_jid()])
        html.start()
        self.response.out.write(html)

app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', przmBatchOutputPage)], debug=True)
```

Comment: Even though the backend has no timeout, I believe the urlfetch api still has the 60s timeout. Try to test it on the server instead of localhost.

Comment: I still got timeout error on a EC2 box.

Comment: Is that the error you see on appengine side? Then maybe the EC2 box takes too long to respond? If you hit the url with the same data / payload using say a python console, how long it take?

Comment: The error messages came from GAE log. I found this error always came up right after 60 seconds. That's way I consider it is a timeout issue.

Comment: Test to hit that endpoint from browser / python console and see how long it takes. If the EC2 responds more than 60s it makes sense if it is timeout

Comment: As someone else said here, the URLFetch is limited to 60 seconds

Comment: @marcadian: The program takes more than 60s to run... So is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @TimHoffman: So it seems like Urlfetch is not a good choice. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You could try using sockets directly instead and in theory you can use a longer timeout. You may need to use a seperate http lib that hasn't been patched to use urlfetch.

Comment: @TimHoffman: I am afraid all http libs in GAE use Urlfetch, but I will checkout sockets.

Comment: have a look at httplib2  you do need billing enabled to use outbound sockets